# Is there a way to map from a list to a scalar property using auto mapper?

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

In my business layer I have the following objects

```cs
class ParentClass
{
    // Parent class properties
    ChildClass PrimaryChild { get; set; }
    ChildClass SecondaryClass { get; set; }
}

class ChildClass
{
    //Child class properties
}
```

The business rules dictate that there will only be a primary and a secondary child

In the DAL, though it made sense to set this up as a standard one to many relationship

```cs
class ParentEntity
{
    // Parent properties
    IEnumerable<ChildEntity> Children { get; set; }
}

class ChildEntity
{
    // Child properties

    bool IsPrimary { get; set; }

    int ParentId { get; set; }
    ParentEntity Parent { get; set; }
}
```

This both works nice for the database and provides future flexibility in the case that the business rules do change.

This all working fine, but I have found myself manually mapping the `PrimaryChild` and `SecondaryChild` properties in the business layer, while everything else is being mapped by automapper.

Is there a way to instruct automapper to do this kind of mapping?  I haven't had any luck in finding an example that follows this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it could be done with something like:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.PrimaryChild ,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Children.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IsPrimary)))

.ForMember(dest => dest.SecondaryClass,
            opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Children.FirstOrDefault(c => !c.IsPrimary)))
```

But it relies on the source data being consistent to how you have explained it and the IsPrimary property being set at point of mapping.

Better to change the ParentClass to hold a collection of ChildClass if practical so you get a direct mapping that will handle data inconsistencies, which you can filter afterwards as needed.

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  I was trying to have my business layer objects' structures reflect the business rules, but I guess there's no reason that I couldn't store the list and implement the logic to filter and expose those properties from within the parent class instead of directly mapping. Thanks.  I might go with this.

Comment: Would give more scope for adapting the BLL logic as needed and handling errors.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, this cannot be implicitly done.

Even if the ability to implicitly do it existed, it would require you to explicitly point out:

- The properties which should be mapped into a list
- How the `IsPrimary` flag should be set based on which of those properties it is
- (for a two-way binding) Which list element should be mapped to which property

As a simple example of how complex it could be: what if your list had several children but *none* which were flagged as the primary? How would you implicitly know what to do?

Once you're already at the point of having written these custom bits of logic, you've basically rewritten your entire manual mapping and the framework wouldn't really be doing much other than executing your manually written steps.

It'd be a whole lot of code that doesn't really add value to the functionality of the library.

Comment: This is what I suspected, but I figured that I'd toss the question out there in case there was a better way to do this.  I'm going to leave the question open for a while, to see if somebody has a better solution, but I think you're right.

Comment: As for the case where the `IsPrimary` flag is not set, I do not allow that.  There are checks on both the business layer and DAL preventing this.  Somebody would need to manually go into the database and cause that problem. My current mapping will take the first record it finds as primary if it does come across this case though.

Comment: @Jesse _"My current mapping will take the first record it finds as primary if it does come across this case though."_ That'd be a fourth bullet point: changing the `IsPrimary` flag value based on the absence of a value in all elements of the list. This is also an example of logic that is so custom-built that it cannot be reasonably abstracted (while providing an actual benefit by abstracting it)

Comment: To clarify, I wasn't expecting it to be automatic, but was thinking that since it is technically mapping code that it might have a better place in the mapping profile than it does in the business layer.